# java.io.EOFException from Cassandra when doing select

Tags: cassandra-2.0

Cassandra 2.06, Oracle Java version "1.7.0_51", Linux Mint 16

I have a cassandra keyspace with about 12 tables that are all the same.

If I load 100,000 rows or so into a couple of those tables in Cassandra, it works fine.

If I load a larger dataset, after a while one of the tables won't do lookups any more (not always the same one).

```
SELECT recv_time,symbol from table6 where mid='S-AUR01-20140324A-1221';
```

results in "Request did not complete within rpc_timeout."

where "mid" is the primary key (varchar). If I look at the logs, it has an EOFException ... presumably it's running out of some resource (it's definitely not out of disk space)

```
    ERROR [ReadStage:110] 2014-04-03 12:39:47,018 CassandraDaemon.java (line 196) Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:110,5,main]
    java.io.IOError: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Column$1.computeNext(Column.java:79)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Column$1.computeNext(Column.java:64)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SimpleSliceReader.computeNext(SimpleSliceReader.java:88)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SimpleSliceReader.computeNext(SimpleSliceReader.java:37)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableSliceIterator.hasNext(SSTableSliceIterator.java:82)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter$2.getNext(QueryFilter.java:157)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter$2.hasNext(QueryFilter.java:140)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$OneToOne.computeNext(MergeIterator.java:200)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter.collectReducedColumns(SliceQueryFilter.java:185)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateColumns(QueryFilter.java:122)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateOnDiskAtom(QueryFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateOnDiskAtom(QueryFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.collectAllData(CollationController.java:297)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.getTopLevelColumns(CollationController.java:53)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getTopLevelColumns(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1551)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1380)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.getRow(Keyspace.java:327)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SliceFromReadCommand.getRow(SliceFromReadCommand.java:65)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$LocalReadRunnable.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1341)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:1896)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.readBytes(RandomAccessReader.java:348)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.read(ByteBufferUtil.java:392)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readWithLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:355)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnSerializer.deserializeColumnBody(ColumnSerializer.java:110)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.OnDiskAtom$Serializer.deserializeFromSSTable(OnDiskAtom.java:85)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Column$1.computeNext(Column.java:75)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a perfect solution, but may make sense to try

```
disk_access_mode: standard
```

This issue seems to be the same thing
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6525

(I was not sure where to set disk_access_mode, but this post says you can add it to cassandra.yaml http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201301.mbox/%3CCA+VSrLouEKurUZ84eRseDNGjuyhC56r6Uk5moHsRD_2ScBs+6g@mail.gmail.com%3E )